# Не запускается служба на сервера

Tags: c#, .net, api, asp.net-core, service

Конфиг: Windows Server 2016, x64, 1Гб ОЗУ
Создал службу по мануалу [Размещение ASP.NET Core в службе Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-2.1) установил на дом. пк, все отлично встало и отработало. Все произвожу точно так же, устанавливаю службу на сервер, но не могу запустить, ошибка 1053 служба не может быть запущена. В чем может быть проблема?

**UPD**

Вот что пишет в EventLog 2 ошибки

1- A timeout was reached (30000 milliseconds) while waiting for the MyService service to connect.

2- The MyService service failed to start due to the following error: 
The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.

Comment: А в event лог-то что пишет?

Comment: @A K добавил описание, но там ничего полезного

Comment: Контрольный вопрос. У вас на инициализации сервиса надеюсь никаких тяжёлых операций не запускается? Таймаут может быть вызван именно этим. Также могу попробовать порекомендовать собрать новое пустое приложение и постепенно добавлять к нему больше реальных фич приложения - и смотреть когда перестанет запускаться.

Comment: @A K стандартно стартовое приложение API ASP.NET CORE вообще пустое, чисто вывод двух значений для проверки. А при старте даже 30 секунд не проходит служба падает

Comment: (в порядке предположения, не уверен, но вдруг?) Версия фреймворка какая? На машине разработчика наверняка установлен со студией, а вот есть ли такая версия на сервере? Что пишет `dotnet -info`. Ну и просто разок запустите на сервере не как службу, а как консольное приложение, убрав RunAsService.

Comment: @A K  Did you mean to run dotnet SDK commands? Please install dotnet SDK from:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409, установил, все по прежнему.

Comment: @A K при запуске консоли оно как и ожидалось сразу закрывается, это же Web приложение, его только в IIS, но IIS на сервере нет поэтому такие ухищрения

Comment: При запуске консоли даже веб приложение не должно закрываться, оно в консоль штатный лог выводит. Проверьте, что все зависимости и файлы конфигураций в наличии, а также прикрутите любой логгер, глобальный перехват эксепшенов, и все выловленное пишите в файл. Почти уверен, что либо какая-то dll не грузится, либо конфиг потерялся.

Comment: и еще вопрос в догонку, как публикуете приложение?

Comment: @rdorn приложение публикую в папку на локалке, потом переношу на сервер и записываю в службы. Логер мне покажет разве из за какой длл не запускается программа?

Comment: Логгер ничего не пишет, так как не запускается не программа а сама служба. А почему, я не знаю. Все длл, сдк и т.д. я аналогично установил на  сервере точно как и на локальном ПК. Студия я на сервере не могу поставить что бы полностью воссоздать похожие моменты...

Comment: @Unnamed проверьте или выдайте себе явно права на запуск службы. Проверить для какой версии core производится сборка и, на всякий случай, переустановить рантайм для core. Как вариант, можно попробовать публикацию self contaned под целевую платформу. Проверить права в папке приложения. Временно выключить антивирь - плохой совет, но тоже стоит попробовать для диагностики если больше ничего не помогает.

Comment: @rdorn по моему какая то проблема в коре, так как в IIS даже не запускается приложение, пишет ошибку на WebConfig но блин, я приложение только создал, и ничего больше не добавлял в длл и тд...

Comment: Попробуйте поставить рантайм бандл для вебсервера https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/thank-you/dotnet-runtime-2.1.5-windows-hosting-bundle-installer